# how i can filter tweets received from statuses/filter streaming API

Tags: python, tweepy, tweets, twitterapi-python, tweetstream

I ma doing research on tweets sentiment analysis.

I have number of different keywords that i want to track (track=['Trump', 'ocean', 'Democrat', 'Republican', 'gardening','BMCSoftware', 'school', 'CT', '#metoo', 'governor', 'Iran']).

Problem is that how I can identify that which tweet corresponds to which keyword.

I tried my best to solve this problem but I can’t.

Please help me to identify tweets related to keywords.

here is my code..

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream

from tweepy import StreamListener
import json
from textblob import TextBlob
import re #Regulor Expretion
import csv
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

class MyListner(StreamListener):
    
    def on_data(self, data):
        raw_twitts=json.loads(data)
        
        try:
            
            created_at=raw_twitts['created_at']
            tweets=raw_twitts['text']
            tweet_id=raw_twitts['id']
            screen_name=raw_twitts['user']['screen_name']
            hasgtages=raw_twitts['entities']['hashtags']
            description = raw_twitts['user']['description']
            retweet=raw_twitts['retweet_count']
    
            with open('Stream_data.csv', 'a') as myFile:
            writer = csv.writer(myFile)
            writer.writerow([created_at,tweet_id,screen_name,hasgtages,description,tweets,retweet])
            

            print("created_at: ",created_at)
            print("id: ",tweet_id)
            print("screen_name: ",screen_name)
            print("hasgtage: ",hasgtages)
            print("description: ",description)
            print("text: ",tweets)
            print("retweet: ",retweet)
            

        except:
            print("Errors got")

        def on_error(self,status):
            print(status)

        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

        twitter_stream=Stream(auth,MyListner())
        twitter_stream.filter(track=['Trump', 'ocean', 'Democrat', 'Republican',     'gardening','BMCSoftware', 'school', 'CT', '#metoo', 'governor', 'Iran'])
```

Comment: I can't see anything in your code that attempts to analyse the JSON response for the keywords that you're interested in. Also, the code for MyListner() might make for interesting viewing

Comment: @AndyKnight Sir please check it again.